# how to add badge button to blogger ( blogspot ) post in homepage

Tags: templates, label, blogger

I want to add button ( like official, new ...etc ) to blogger template posts in homepage
How to do this ?

---

[image]

---

The general idea is that the official button is displayed when we add a label with a name, for example "official"
I try with this code but not working:

```
`<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
  <b:if cond='data:post.labels and data:post.labels.size == 1 and data:post.labels[0].name == "Official"'>
    <!-- Code to display each post -->
    <!-- Insert the button code here -->
    <a href="LINK_TO_YOUR_PAGE" target="_blank">
      <img src="IMAGE_URL" alt="Official Button" style="width: 200px; height: auto;" />
    </a>
  </b:if>
</b:loop>`
```